# Why does the WebGrid use dynamic in formatting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, .net-4.0, lambda, webgrid

I'm working with the `System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid` in an ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor project, and I'm having trouble understanding why the format parameter for a `WebGridColumn` is a `Func<dynamic, object>`.

If I create a column like this...

```
grid.Column(
    format: x => string.Format("{0:d}", x.StartDate)
    );
```

...I don't get strong typing on the StartDate property.  If I try to get around it like this...

```
grid.Column(
    format: (MyObjectType x) => string.Format("{0:d}", x.StartDate)
    );
```

...I'm told at runtime that my lambda can't be cast to a `Func<dynamic, object>`.  Is there some way I can use a non-dynamic lambda here?  Even if it's just `<object, object>`?

(I'm in .NET 4.0, and `Func<in T, out TResult>` is supposed to be contravariant on T, but I'm confused about how covariance and contravariance work with dynamic.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the type system is concerned, `dynamic` is the same as `object`.

They cannot use a strongly-typed delegate because they don't have a strongly-typed value to pass.

Inside `WebGrid`, they get an `Object` from a `PropertyDescriptor`, and pass that to your delegate.

Covariance won't help here; had `Func<YourType, string>` been convertible to `Func<object, string>`, it would be possible to call it with any other type and get an invalid cast.

Comment: With object I can get an invalid cast, but with dynamic I'll get an error if `StartDate` doesn't exist at runtime.  Six of one, half a dozen of the other.  But as it is, if I change the `StartDate` property to, say, `InitialDate`, this MVC view will break at runtime; I won't be able to detect it even if I enable building views at compile time.

Comment: @Kyralessa: You can cast in the delegate: `x => string.Format("{0:d}", ((YourType)x).StartDate)`

Comment: Only in the WebGridColumn's format param, x ends up as a WebGridRow so it has to be `x => string.Format("{0:d}", ((MyType)x.Value).StartDate);`.  Rather hideous.

Comment: Hideous and, it seems to me, entirely unnecessary.  Why didn't they use generics in the `WebGrid`?

Comment: @Kyralessa: To allow it to be used with things like `DataTable`, which aren't generic.  (Or with `IListSource` in generic classes)

Comment: A reasonable answer, I guess, but mainly what it told me is that the WebGrid is not for a static type of guy like me.  I ended up using the MvcContrib grid instead, which worked a lot better.

Comment: @Kyralessa: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx, which shows you how to make a generic WebGrid wrapper.